# Prometheus/grafana combined labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

What I need is to make a separate grafana dashboard filter for each url. For example I have urls like:

- GET v1/users
- POST v1/users
- PUT v1/users
- DELETE v1/users/{id}
- GET v1/users/{id}

and in Prometheus they are stored like:

```
http_responses_total{ method="GET", path="v1/users", status="200"}
http_responses_total{ method="POST", path="v1/users", status="200"}
http_responses_total{ method="PUT", path="v1/users", status="200"}
http_responses_total{ method="DELETE", path="v1/users/{id}", status="200"}
http_responses_total{ method="GET", path="v1/users/{id}", status="200"}
```

and I can make a dashboard variable like:

```
label_values(api_requests_total,route)
```

which will generate the list like:

- all
- v1/users
- v1/users/{id}

or

```
label_values(api_requests_total,method)
```

which will generate the list like:

- all
- GET
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE

but I want to generate a list like:

- All
- GET v1/users
- POST v1/users
- PUT v1/users
- DELETE v1/users/{id}
- GET v1/users/{id}